# firebase database.ref().once callback never called (javascript, ionic)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a firebase app with the ionic framework using javascript. All of my database writing operations work but I can't read data no matter what I try.

I have inside a function:

```
  setCompanyAndTitle(){
    let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let userRef = this.database.ref('users/'+uid);
    userRef.once('value').then(function(user){
      alert("pls " + user.displayName);
    //NEVER CALLED  !!!!!!!!
    }).catch(function(error){
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      alert(errorMessage);
    //NEVER CALLED  !!!!!!!!!
    });

  }
```

My firebase is initialized like so:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "000000000"
  });
```

I cant get the once() function to make a callback no matter what I try.

Comment: Is `this.database` defined?  If not, try replacing it with `firebase.database()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `let userRef = this.database.ref('users/'+uid);` to `let userRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+uid);`. Also, you should access your response like so:

```
userRef.once('value').then(function(userSnapshot){
      cont user = userSnapshot.val()
      alert("pls " + user.displayName);
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. this.database was defined as firebase.database() in the class declarations. I tried with a const user but the callback function still never gets called...